# How to do live data analysis?

Tags: apache-kafka, data-analysis, data-presentation

I have worked with R to do data analysis for making prediction model. Now I need to build solution for live data analysis. That's find patterns from data and show an alert if some condition is going to occur.

```
Like if I am receiving RSSI from the sensors. First find patterns if it has any relation with battery level and show alert if the live data shows that pattern from live RSSI data.
```

I did a little search and in one reply on Quora, a linked tool **Kafka** is mentioned for doing such stuff. I don't have any experience of working with Kafka.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could start by exploring [KSQL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/index.html)? Not knowing your schema here's a naive query against a theoretical Kafka topic with live RSSI data:

```
CREATE STREAM rssi_data 
    (device_id VARCHAR,
     battery_level INT,
     SIGNAL FLOAT)
 WITH (TOPIC='rssi_data', VALUE_FORMAT='json', KEY='device_id');
```

and then query it:

```
CREATE STREAM low_battery_devices AS SELECT * FROM rssi_data WHERE battery_level < 20;
```

That would create a new Kafka topic called `low_bettery_devices` which would contain events for the devices who's battery is lower. You can then of course consume that topic with another KSQL query, or an R program or some other downstream Kafka compatible system.